# How to handle Master Data Update effectively, Something like PTA(Point In Time Architecture) design

Tags: c#, sql, database-design, sql-server-2012

While designing, I encountered a problem for my VB.NET based Winforms Application.

I am storing some master data in my database as a first step of my software cycle.

That master data will be used to make Purchase and Sale entry in my software's Voucher section.

Suppose user selects an item in Purchase section, I retrieve all the item's information from database and then on save, Purchase voucher is saved with that information.

Now suppose, user changes master item details, i.e. price, weight.

It works fine for new entry. When I open old entry, it will show the new price and weight though it should show old price and weight as this entry is old.

How can I avoid this design/workflow problem in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You should normalize your data. Do not store copies of data in your database. Create entities and store only relations between them.

Read some tutorials on database normalization

Comment: Can you give me some links in which I can get idea about managing previous data of that entity?

Comment: @Hemal What do you mean "previous"? Do you maintain a history of records?

Comment: Previous means 'Past data', the data that is being updated. Suppose If I update a price of product from '30' to '35', then I need to have both prices in database so that I can show 30 for past bills and 35 for future bills.